# Ubuntu Shut down app

Tags: shutdown

does anybody knows a good Ubuntu Shut down app or manager or commands? I have Gshutdown installed but there's a lack of options I need more advanced one so I could shut it down automatically daily or once a week whatever, for example every day at 02:00 am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an entry to the *root* crontab, roughly like this ([original discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=925450))
`sudo crontab -e`

```
# Shutdown every day at 02:00 am
0 2 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```